# Are there any continuous and closed form formulas for extending the multiple angle formulas to rational multiples?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have been poking at this for a while and was unable to find much info relating to specifically extending these formulas:

$\sin(\frac{x}{2}) = \sqrt\frac{1-\cos x}{2}$

$\sin(2x)= 2\cos x \sin x$

to something of the form:

$\sin(\frac{p}{q}x)$ where $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$

For example: using the angle addition formula for sin, 
I got $\sin (\frac{3x}{2}) = \sin x \sqrt{\frac{1+ \cos x}{2}} + \cos x \sqrt{\frac{1- \cos x}{2}}$

However, when plotting this, it seems to work, but only for a small, periodic interval.
[Image of plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rKbK.png)

Is there a particular reason for this? I'm thinking it has to do with the square root as simplifying or messing with equivalent forms of the equation gives similar plots, but with the intervals shifted over.

Is there no way to have a formula for these rational multiples that works everywhere?

Comment: Those half angle formulas aren't always correct. What do you think happens when $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ for example?

Comment: Also you have your sine and your cosine half angle formulas backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, because a formula for
$\sin(px/q)$
would invert the expression for
$\sin(qx)$ and this is a polynomial of degree $q$.

Of course, this polynomial has a special form, so it might be solvable.